# Reading a text file and store each line into a list in Rstudio

Tags: r, list, text, readline

I am trying to read a text file containing some words in each line. I would like to store each line as an element into a list. 
I am using the following command:

```
listOfNames = readLines("text.txt")
```

I am getting the following result:

```
[1] "\"string1\""                                   
[2] "\"string2\""                                   
[3] "\"string3\""
```

How can I get rid of the "\" and extra " symbols. 
my desired output looks like the following.

```
[1] "string1"                                   
[2] "string2"                                   
[3] "string3"
```

Do you have any idea how can I fix this? 
Thanks,

Comment: Use `read.csv("text.txt")` instead to (if your file contains only one column per word or expression). You will get a `data.frame` which is nothing but a `list` with named columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your input contain quotes(?) You can remove these with gsub()

```
listOfNames <- gsub("\"" ,"", listOfNames)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
listOfNames =  data.table("text.txt")
```

to get a data.frame. If you need a list, you can use

```
listOfNames = as.list(unlist(data.table("text.txt")))
```

The function `data.table()` like its alias (for example `read.csv()`) contain a parameter quote which handels ' and " by default. If you every need another quote, you can change the parameter.